# PKIX path building failed: Certificate not found

Tags: java, x509certificate

I have added new certificate to my keystore and when I am running my application and it tries to read certificate from TrustStore using method checkServerCerts in CertificateMessage class, it always reflect same certificate and the count is always 7 even if i added new certificates to my cacert. My question is from which location truststore reads and pick up the certificate.

Comment: You wrote in your question: _I have added new certificate to my keystore_ Can you [edit] your question and post the command you used to add the certificate? You also wrote: _the count is always 7_ Can you post the code you wrote to get that count?

Comment: There is a class CertificateMessgae under package sun.security.ssl; This class has a method checkClientCerts, there I am getting the list of certificate

Answer (score 0):

They are stored in `<JAVA_HOME>/lib/security/cacerts` by default.
Use keytool in your `<JAVA_HOME>/bin` folder to manage this.

Answer (score 0):

I used below code and it worked for me. You need to do same for KeyStore as well

```
FileInputStream myKeys = new FileInputStream("C:\\certs\\TrustStore.jks");

// Do the same with your trust store this time
// Adapt how you load the keystore to your needs
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
// Using null here initialises the TMF with the default trust store.
tmf.init((KeyStore) null);

KeyStore myTrustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
myTrustStore.load(myKeys, "password".toCharArray());

myKeys.close();

tmf = TrustManagerFactory
        .getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
tmf.init(myTrustStore);

return tmf.getTrustManagers()[0];
```